# Probability of intersection of at least 2 line segments

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Let there be a line segment of length X. Let there be Y line segments of length K combined, they are put on a random place WITHIN first segment. What is the probability that at least 2 of line segments out of K intersect meaning that they will have at least 1 common point?

Comment: Are the $Y$ segments all the same length?

Comment: I guess they are.

Comment: @AndruxaStalker What have you found out when $Y=2$? Make a sketch.